# MongoDB JSON File not loading

Tags: json, mongodb, file, loading

I am trying to load a json file on to my MongoDB. When I try to load it I keep getting this error....

error validating settings: incompatible options: --file and positional argument(s)

What is the problem?

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)’s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful - despite its harsh title.

Comment: Please provide the exact command you are running, with the arguments.